# Small layout no space for object, how can I deal with this in code

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Basically in my app I have a 'graph' (from holographlibrary). That is irrelevant though, we'll just call it a textview.

So in my layout-small files I do not have set textview that I have in my layout-normal files. So if I run the app on a small screen, when the code tries to find it, it can't and the app crashes.

Is there some easy way to only call findviewbyid if it is the the layout file, and then stop the other code involving it from running.

Comment: Use scroll view and place all in one layout. U can too include layout.

Comment: I was looking for something else... Any other ideas?

Comment: What exactly U are looking for

Comment: Is there some easy way to only call findviewbyid for it if it is not the layout-small, and then stop the other code involving it from running.

Comment: U are fallowing wrong way by wondering for small / large layout. This really sense nothing. All U need is to put your requirement one by one .

Comment: I don't want to put requirements on the app, that limits it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
final View v = findViewById(R.id.myId);

if (v != null) {
    // Run code
}
```

For width and height to be > 0:

```
v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                        this);

                // Use v.getWidth() / v.getHeight() now
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the crash trace?

Comment: No because I am way past it now, but it would crash because it couldn't find it because length and width must be > 0

Comment: I updated my answer where you can use the size of View